# Getting the middle column value with the other two column values using xpath in web table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation, browser-automation

```html
<tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
```

[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp]

you can find the sample web table in the link. I want contact value with the company and country.

I have tried something like this

```
//td[text()='Laughing Bacchus Winecellars']//following-sibling::td and //td[text()='Canada']//preceding-sibling::td
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to select required `td` node:

```
//td[preceding-sibling::td[.="Alfreds Futterkiste"] and following-sibling::td[.="Germany"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the middle column value i.e. *`Maria Anders`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the Company text *Alfreds Futterkiste*:

  - `xpath`:

    ```
    //table[@id='customers']//tr//td[text()='Alfreds Futterkiste']//following::td[1]
    ```
  - Line of code:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']//tr//td[text()='Alfreds Futterkiste']//following::td[1]"))).getText());
    ```
- Using the Country text *Germany*:

  - `xpath`:

    ```
    //table[@id='customers']//tr//td[text()='Germany']//preceding::td[1]
    ```
  - Line of code:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']//tr//td[text()='Germany']//preceding::td[1]"))).getText());
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough the `<tr>` and use `//tr/td[2]` to select the second `<td>`.

http://xpather.com/aHyybZni

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath:

```
//td[preceding-sibling::td[text()='Laughing Bacchus Winecellars'] and following-sibling::td[text()='Canada']]
```